# elephant-bird-pig : build error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, elephantbird

I am trying to build elephant bird pig and it is erroring out with the following issue:

```
[INFO] Building Elephant Bird Pig 4.13-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Elephant Bird ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.403 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hadoop Compatibility ................. SUCCESS [  0.758 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Core ................................. SUCCESS [  2.457 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Cascading2 ........................... SUCCESS [  0.040 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Crunch ............................... SUCCESS [  0.100 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hive ................................. SUCCESS [  0.175 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig .................................. FAILURE [  0.061 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Mahout ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird RCFile ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Lucene ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig Lucene ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.452 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-25T21:10:37+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/437M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project elephant-bird-pig: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-pig:jar:4.13-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:jar:tests:4.13-SNAPSHOT http://maven.twttr.com
```

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: I did try skipping test like this:
   mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package

Comment: I do not find the jars here : http://maven.twttr.com/com/twitter/elephant-bird/
any alternate mirrors??